# Does JavaScript have geometric primitives like point, rectangle, etc.?

Tags: javascript, canvas, drawing, geometry

Does JavaScript have geometric primitives like point and rectangle, or do I need to define my own?

Alternatively a good, simple library for it would be a great help, if there is one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript doesn't really.  There are a bunch of graphics libraries available.  You might look at [processing.js](http://processingjs.org/) and [raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/).

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to draw geometric images using only HTML,CSS.Even not javascript.I know a tool which can help you to create whatever geometric image you want,and it'll give you the source HTML and CSS code.It's very cool tool.Here is the link

http://www.w3docs.com/tools/html-geometric-images/